# Densities which are equivalent to Lebesgue measure

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Is it correct that every probability distribution which has a density function $\mu$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$, with the condition that $\mu$ is strictly positive over sets of strictly positive measure is in fact equivalent to the Lebesgue measure ?

That is $μ\ll λ$ and $λ\ll μ$

Comment: what you you think? What about $\mu:=3\lambda$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already given that $\mu \gg \lambda$ from the stated condition.

If $\mu$ has a density $f$ with respect to $\lambda$, then if $\lambda(A) = 0$ then $\mu(A) = \int_A f \, d\lambda = 0$ as well, so $\mu \ll \lambda$.